# z3.prove is much faster than solver and check

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm using latest z3 master code from Codeplex, tagged as v4.3.1.

I want a function like `prove` that has a useful return value and does not print. So, I wrote what seemed obvious:

```
def prove2(claim):
    s = Solver()
    s.add(Not(claim))
    if s.check() == unsat:
        return True, []
    return False, s.model()
```

However, this code runs dramatically slower than the default `prove` function.

The code for `prove` (slimmed) in `src/api/python/z3.py` is:

```
def prove(claim, **keywords):
    s = Solver()
    s.set(**keywords)
    s.add(Not(claim))
    if keywords.get('show', False):
        print s
    r = s.check()
    if r == unsat:
        print "proved"
    elif r == unknown:
        print "failed to prove"
        print s.model()
    else:
        print "counterexample"
        print s.model()
```

When I add `s.set()` to my code, it is fast and finds the same counterexample.

What is going on here?

- Does that empty call to `s.set()` somehow clear some option that is bad in general?
- .. bad for my particular test?
- Something else?

I tried to find out what the default solver options were, but `str(s)` `repr(s)`, `s.__dict__`, and google didn't really help.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: That's an interesting observation. There's currently no convenient way to get the solver options off of a Solver object. Could you perhaps to see what's in **keywords at runtime?

Comment: Hi @ChristophWintersteiger, since I'm the one calling `prove(claim)`, I know that `**keywords` is the empty dictionary.

Comment: Interesting. What exactly do you understand as "dramatically slower"? Do you have a small benchmark that triggers this behaviour?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger I had an example 9 days ago ;) but I just uncommented the empty call to `set()` and ran my program again and it seemed fine. Maybe I hit a bad RNG state in the one case, I guess... ?

Comment: Interesting! Good to know everything's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is that the default options did poorly for my particular case, perhaps because of a random number difference or some other non-deterministic internal state.